# What does `Forky (a -> b) means in type declaration?

Tags: haskell, type-declaration

This is from some exercise:

```
(<*>) :: Forky (a -> b) -> Forky a -> Forky b
```

where Forky is defined as

```
data Forky a = Tip a | Branch (Forky a) (Forky a)
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Usually, I see `(a -> b)` as a function in the type declaration. But what does `Forky (a -> b)` means?

Answer (score 2):

`a -> b` is a type like any other. Substituting it into the `Forky` declaration means that the first argument to your `<*>` operator will be either a `Tip f` (where `f :: a -> b`) or a `Branch` consisting of two `Forky (a -> b)`. `Forky (a -> b)` is just like a `Forky Int`, except instead of containing integers at the leaves, it contains functions.

Answer (score 2):

`a -> b` is still a function type; here, the type constructor `Forky` is applied to it to get another type. Since `Forky a` is basically a type of binary trees containing `a` values, `Forky (a -> b)` is a tree containing functions.

Note the similarities:

```
data Forky a = Tip  a | Branch (Forky a) (Forky a)
data Tree  a = Leaf a | Node   (Tree  a) (Tree  a)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a list of three functions

```
funcs :: [Int -> Int]
funcs = [ abs, \x -> 2*x+1, (`mod` 16) ]
```

Here's a function that maybe returns a function:

```
adder :: Int -> Maybe (Int -> Int)
adder n
    | n > 0 = Just (\m -> n + m)
    | otherwise = Nothing
```

Here's a function that takes a maybe function as an argument:

```
applyMay :: Maybe (a -> a) -> a -> a
applyMay Nothing x = x
applyMay (Just f) x = f x
```